# Django session language doesn't apply to the first page the user lands on

Tags: django, session, translation

To show my landing page in the correct language, I manually fetch the language setting, set the session language, and then render the template.

The trouble is that the first rendering of the landing page is not translated. I have to click through to another page before the session language is taken into account when rendering the templates. If I then navigate back to the landing page, it appears correctly translated.

I presume this is because a session cookie with the language info needs to be written on the client side? What's the Right Way™ to set session language? Should I just have a view dedicated to writing this cookie and then somehow redirecting?

#### views.py

```
from django.utils import translation
def landing_page(request):
    profile = Profiles.objects.get(user=request.user)
    request.session[translation.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = profile.language`
    return render(request, "my_template.html")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't to do with cookies. It's rather that the code that activates the language based on the session value lives in the LocaleMiddleware, and that is run before the view. If you want to change the language for your current view, you need to do it manually:

```
translation.activate(profile.language)
```